# Can any parts of my code be parallelised

Tags: java

I am curious as to wether any parts of my code can be parallelised and if so what is hindering that conversion.

```
package factorial;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Factorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    int n,i,f;    
    String numInput;
    numInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number:");
    n = Integer.parseInt(numInput);
    //... Computation

     f =1;
    for(i=n;i>=1;i--){      
     f = f*i;
    }
    //... Output
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Factorial value is: " +f);
  }

 }
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate factorial IS parallisable.

Comment: @litelite Whoops, read the answer and realized you were right. My bad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, because you can execute the multiplications in any order. It is just like writing (1*2*3)*(4*5*6). Execute each parenthesis individually in a thread and multiply both result together and voilà!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly shard this into any number of threads that generate a subset of the answer and then multiply the outputs when they all complete. This is the classic [mapreduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html) example.